# Email templates with ASP.NET MVC 2, .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, email-templates

I am trying to avoid using `StringBuilder` to generate e-mails and was hoping to find a solution to dynamically create e-mail templates using:

1. .NET 3.5
2. ASP.NET MVC 2
3. Visual Studio 2008

I have searched, but most seem to require .NET 4 or ASP.NET MVC 3+.  Is there anything that would support my requirements?

Comment: Do you want to dynamically create email templates or dynamically create emails using some pre-defined templates?

Comment: @ataravati - Both actually.

Comment: For dynamically creating emails, I usually create my own text or html files and use them as templates. I use my own way of creating placeholders for things that need to be replaced, like "Hello ##UserName##,...", and then I replace ##UserName## with the actual name from the database.